# SSH jumphost error: channel 0: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ubuntu-17.04

I'm trying to open an ssh connection with following command:

```
ssh -J user@X.X.X.X user@10.10.1.1
```

with following error:

```
channel 0: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed
stdio forwarding failed
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

At the Server there is PermitTunnel active. The OS of the server is Ubuntu 17.04.

Do you have an hint for me what there is wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The problem waw the firewall. ICMP was blocked. After acepting the icmp traffic the ssh jumphost is working as it should.